# Is there any rule about why is the redefinition of the enumerator ill-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this example

```cpp
enum class A{
    a = 0,
    a = 1
};
```

The [compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/v3xaTh6Mq) will report an error, which is the "redefinition of enumerator 'a'". However, [[basic.def.odr#1]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#1) does not have any requirement for the **enumerator**

> No translation unit shall contain more than one **definition** of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, template, default argument for a parameter (for a function in a given scope), or default template argument.

I wonder which normative rule, in the standard, is restricting that?

Comment: Maybe, 10.2 Enumeration declarations \[dcl.enum] _11. Each enum-name and each unscoped enumerator is declared in the scope that immediately contains the
enum-specifier. Each scoped enumerator is declared in the scope of the enumeration. These names obey the
scope rules defined for all names in 6.3 and 6.4._ [N4713, page 158](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat According to [basic.link#8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#8) they declare the same entity, which don't violate [basic.scope#declarative-4.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope#declarative-4.1)

Comment: How can it refer to the same entity, if there are two separate entities named `a`? Before the second `a` declaration, an identifier `a` refers to the first `a`, and after it - to the second `a`.

Comment: @rustyx At least, according to basic.link#8, they are. Unless we can find some rules that prove they aren't. In this example, the two declarations correspond and have the same target scope, hence they declare the same entity.

Comment: Who cares? It's an oversight. File a defect and move on.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.   Which part is the defect you are saying?

Comment: The part that doesn't say that this is illegal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Original answer

Yes, as of now, the One Definition Rule in the C++ standard doesn't include enumerators.

However, the "the second `a` is a redeclaration of the first `a`" explanation doesn't work too.
From [[dcl.enum#nt:enumerator-list]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#nt:enumerator-list) we can know that an *enumerator-list* is a list of *enumerator-definition*, so they're all definitions.

```
enumerator-list:
    enumerator-definition
    enumerator-list , enumerator-definition
```

**Why isn't enumerator included in the one definition rule? That's likely an oversight on the standard committee's part.** Considering that in C, enumerators **are** prohibited from redefinition.

From [the draft of C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), Section 6.7:

> 5
>
> A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. **A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that**:
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
> — for a function, includes the function body;101)
> — for an **enumeration constant** or typedef name, **is the (only) declaration of the identifier**.

From Section 6.7.2.2 we can see an enumerator is an enumeration-constant:

```
enumerator:
    enumeration-constant
    enumeration-constant = constant-expression
```

And from 6.7.2.2 one can also infer that all enumerator in a enumerator-list will always be not only declared but also **defined**.

> 3
>
> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.
> An enumerator **with = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression. If the first enumerator has no =, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant.** (The use of enumerators with = may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.) The enumerators of an enumeration are also known as its members.

So in C, you can't define an enumerator with the same identifier for more than one time, because if you can, it will no longer be the only declaration of the identifier, which makes it an invalid definition according to Section 6.7.

The behaviour in C might be why almost all C++ compiler prohibits redefinition of enumerator, and it is likely the intended or expected behaviour of C++ too.

## Update

**Update 2022-02-16**: I've submitted an issue regarding this question following the procedure detailed in https://isocpp.org/std/submit-issue. **It's been accepted and is now [Issue 2530](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2530).**

Comment: *the "the second a is a redeclaration of the first a" explanation doesn't work too*, it does work since they correspond and declared the same entity.

Comment: @xmh0511 There's literally no way to declare a enumerator and not define it at the same time, both in C and C++. So the second time will always be a (re)definition, which is prohibited by C and weirdly not by C++, which might be a mistake.

Comment: _turns out this case is actually covered by the C++ standard_ … _paragraph 5 says that the program is ill-formed if corresponding declarations appear in the same scope and one precedes the other_ **And if declarations denote different entities**, but they denote the same per http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#8, which is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602375/is-there-any-rule-about-why-is-the-redefinition-of-the-enumerator-ill-formed#comment121240323_68602375

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks for pointing out. It's been half a year since answering this question and I've forgot some of the details while updating the answer. I've sent a follow up email to William M. Miller and will update this answer as soon as new information comes out.